# Bootstrap badge badge primary tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently i am following a React Tutorial by Mosh, where he wants to use `badge badge-primary` in a span tag.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <span className="badge badge-primary">{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button>Increment</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
  formatCount() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }
}
export default Counter;
```

With the index.js file looking like this

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Counter from "./components/counter";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Counter />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
reportWebVitals();
```

Bootstrap is actually working, because I can see the website changing. But from what it looks on bootstrap's website it should turn blue, but my text just turns invisible (had to mark it to make it visible)
[Bootstrap Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABpnr.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`badge badge-primary` is from Bootstrap v4. Try `badge bg-primary` instead, which is from Bootstrap v5 (current version). You can check the Bootstrap version from `node_modules` folder > `bootstrap` folder> `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

The font color for that class is white which is why it is disappearing when you appl it... I asssume the intend is to have the
button with the text "increment" and then the badge adjacent. You just need to wrap the button around the span element and apply the primary button class to that button (which is blue)

```
      <React.Fragment>
        <button className="btn btn-primary">
        Increment <span className="badge badge-light">{this.formatCount()}</span>
        </button>
     </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: This makes the button blue. I'd like to keep the button the way it is in the screenshot. The positioning is just fine aswell. I'd just like the text to be blue, the way the button would, if i used ur code instead of mine. How would i do that?

Comment: I think your issue may be that this tutorial is using bootstrap 4 but you have boostrap 5 as your dependency.... You can either just use bootstrap 4 or use the updated className for bootstrap 5 which is : `badge bg-primary`  Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/badge/

Answer (score 0):

For BootStrap v5

this worked

```
<span className="badge bg-primary">{this.formatCount()}</span>
```